# Derive the input and output resistances and the open circuit gain for a common base amplifier, using the pi model and T models

Tags: bjt

Can someone help me derive the input and output resistances and the open circuit gain for a common base amplifier, using the pi model and T models? Please assume Va to be early voltage and no external resistor.

Circuit: [image]

Please note: I'm a newbie, and will really appreciate it if someone can either help me with the derivation or share resources for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feE7bb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_5+\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2+\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_6
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}}{\text{R}_1}&=\text{I}_5+\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}}{\text{R}_1}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_2}+\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\text{V}}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_6
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for the input resistance \$\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{i}:=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{I}_5}\$ as follows:

$$\text{R}_\text{i}:=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{I}_5}=\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{n}\right)\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag4$$

---

I used the following mathematica-code to solve this question:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I5 + n*I2, I1 == I0 + I2 + n*I2, I0 == I3 + I4, 
   I6 == I3 + I4, I5 == I2 + I6, I1 == (Vi - V)/R1, I2 == V/R2, 
   I3 == V/R3, I4 == V/R4}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4), 
  I1 -> (((1 + n) R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)) Vi)/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4), 
  I2 -> (R3 R4 Vi)/(R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4), 
  I3 -> (R2 R4 Vi)/(R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4), 
  I4 -> (R2 R3 Vi)/(R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4), 
  I5 -> ((R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)) Vi)/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4), 
  I6 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4), 
  V -> (R2 R3 R4 Vi)/(R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3) R4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I derive Rout and Open circuit gain for this?